"Best" wavefunction for the $\rm H_2$ molecule
The Schrödinger equation for the hydrogen atom is of course exactly soluble. Once we get to two-electron problems, there are no analytical expressions for the wavefunctions. However, we can still try to use something like the variational principle to obtain very good approximations to the exact thing.
For the helium atom, I know a good way to express the wavefunction is in terms of the Hylleraas correlated wavefunctions.
However, another important two-electron problem is the $\rm H_2$ molecule (in the Born-Oppenheimer approximation). Is there any set of functions that allows one to express the exact wavefunction to a very high degree of accuracy (like the Hylleraas wavefunctions for helium)?

Heitler-London wave function?

The $H_2^+$ molecule (in the Born Oppenheimer approximation) is exactly solvable using elliptic coordinates

@LPZ It is indeed, but that is quite irrelevant to the question, since the H2 molecule has one more electron. This is like the difference between the hydrogen and helium atoms.

@Mass If I am not mistaken (and I well may be), the Heitler-London approach breaks the wavefunction into 1-electron functions. It is still able to describe bond-breaking (unlike Hartree-Fock), but it cannot be the best one can do - e.g. it does not include "explicitly correlated" terms which depend on the distance between electrons.
